# iOS how to make difference between images iPhone 5 iPhone 7?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

After a long search, I didnt find anything. 
I understood that x2 images are used for Retina screen but how can I make a difference between devices ?? Storyboard or code ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi! Could you add in some code or detail for things that you've tried, maybe describing any error or what you expected would happen? You're much more likely to get an answer if you can add more detail about what you're doing. Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Why do you need to make a difference? From the image name (image.png, image@2x.png) you can't.

Comment: Because my image on the iPhone 5 is really big instead of on iPhone 6, it looks perfectly